# Immer reducer does not work with Typescript

Tags: reactjs, redux, immer.js

I have a problem with reducer created by immer.js in TypeScript.

I don't understand the following:

When I use an object literal {} in initial state immutability works fine but once

```
const byId = (state = {}, action) =>
    produce(state, draft => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case RECEIVE_PRODUCTS:
               ...
)
        }
    })
```

I change literal to instance of object immutability stop works

```
const byId = (state = new SomeObject(), action) =>
    produce(state, draft => {
        switch (action.type) {
            case RECEIVE_PRODUCTS:
               ...
)
        }
    })
```

Can you someone idea why?

Thanks..

Comment: Plese share code for `SomeObject()` and what is `produce()` function?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You typically want the first argument to `produce` to be a plain object or array.

Optionally it could be an "immerable class", though I'm not familiar with what that would be specifically (sounds like an internal thing to me) but it's not likely what your `new SomeObject()` call returns.

https://github.com/immerjs/immer/blob/master/src/immer.js#L61

If the first argument to `produce` is not one of these then it will not be "drafted".

https://github.com/immerjs/immer/blob/master/src/common.js#L20

Answer (score 0):

I have created parent object

```
export class Immerable {
  public [immerable] = true;
}
```

and all classes which I need to use within produce function has this parent. Thanks.